# Read public method values and assing to a textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am using the below code to get some values from other page and assign the name and value to the text box. But the below code, I can read the name and value to new_ and new_1 string. But i can't assign the two value to textbox. It returns the error message `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`

My partial code is here..

```
public void load_directions(string name, string value)
        {
            try
            {
                txt_name.Text = name.ToString();
                txt_value.Text = value.ToString();
            }
            catch(Exception e1)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Assing to a textbox can be difficult without a donkey.

Comment: I can't understand please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: @leppie : There is no error produced in your code. Can you paste some more code to understand the problem properly?

Comment: @Dev: Why are you asking me, I am not the one donkeying around.

Comment: Why are you calling ToString on a string? It's a string already....

Answer (score 0):

Change your code
 txt_name.Text = name as string;
 txt_value.Text = value as string;

also let us know the calling of load_directions method